# Am I missing a flag or something? RewriteRule tip needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?p=$1&l=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ index.php?p=$1&l=$2
```

this works fine if I do site.com/param_one/param_two/, but returns a 404 when I omit param_two. I'm a newbie to routing requests with htaccess, is there a simple quick fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantifier `+` means *one or more repetitions*. But `/param_one/` would require *zero or more repetitions*. So try the `*` quantifier to have zero or more repetitions:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$ index.php?p=$1&l=$2
```

Comment: Quick question, I tried adding another tier using the same logic (RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/$ index.php?p=$1&l=$2&i=$3) and it started returning 404. am I missing something again or is this not going to work?

Comment: @Kirill: What URL did you test that with?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. Omitting param 2 and 3 and only while supplying the first one gives a 404, while supplying all 3 works fine. I did use the trailing slash (I modified both).
site.com/one - 404, site.com/one/two/three works fine

Comment: @Kirill: You also need to make the separating `/` optional with `/?`.